# Java SimpleDateFormat accepts invalid date. with format 'MM/dd/yyyy' parses '01/01/2021anything'

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse a string date value to date object.
If the provided date is not in the correct format, error has to be thrown.
Trying to achieve this with `SimpleDateFormat`, but Its not working as expected.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
sdf.setLenient(false);
Date d = sdf.parse("01/01/2021anything");
System.out.println(d);
```

For the above code getting output `Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2021` where I expected `ParseException`. Can someone explain why this happens and how I can validate the above date with `SimpleDateFormat`. Appreciate the effort.

Comment: [The JavaDocs of `SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) state *parsing does not necessarily use all characters up to the end of the string*. I think that's the reason for this behaviour.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because it is implemented this way.

`SimpleDateFormat` will inspect the format, and start to parse each token present in the format, but does not necessarily parse the whole string, according to [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)):

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a date. The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

You shouldn't be using `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date` anyways, because they have [more problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api) than this one.

Use classes from the `java.time` package instead. In your case, you should probably be using `LocalDate`. A simple translation of your code to code using `java.time` would be something like this:

```java
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
LocalDate d = LocalDate.parse("01/01/2021anything", formatter);
System.out.println(d);
```

The abovementioned code will throw a `DateTimeParseException`, because it doesn't like *anything*.